# What is the Kraus representation of the quantum channel with Choi $\lambda |\phi^+\rangle \langle\phi^+| + (1-\lambda )|\phi^-\rangle \langle\phi^-|$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-operation, kraus-representation

This matrix

$$c_{\lambda} = \lambda |\phi^+\rangle \langle\phi^+| + (1-\lambda )|\phi^-\rangle \langle\phi^-|$$

is  the Choi–Jamiołkowski matrix of a quantum channel for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

The questions I am trying to solve are:

Provide a Kraus (operator-sum) representation of the quantum channel $T_{\lambda}$ that is described by $c_{\lambda}$ and show that $T_{1/2}$ is an entanglement breaking quantum channel and describe its action on the bloch sphere.

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16393/55

Comment: Yes, I wrote that one :) @glS

Comment: I'm aware. I added the comment because it creates a two-way link between the questions

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to observe that Choi $J(\Phi)\in\mathrm{Lin}(\mathcal Y\otimes\mathcal X)$ and Kraus operators $\{A_a\}_a\subset\mathrm{Lin}(\mathcal X,\mathcal Y)$ of a map $\Phi:\mathrm{Lin}(\mathcal X)\to\mathrm{Lin}(\mathcal Y)$ are directly related via
$$J(\Phi) = \sum_a \operatorname{vec}(A_a)\operatorname{vec}(A_a)^\dagger,$$
where $\operatorname{vec}(A_a)\in\mathcal Y\otimes\mathcal X$ is the vector with components $\operatorname{vec}(A_a)_{ij}=(A_a)_{ij}$.

Therefore, if a Choi is a rank-one projection of the form $|u\rangle\!\langle u|$, then $\operatorname{vec}(A_a)=|u\rangle$, *i.e.* $A_a=\sum_{ij}\langle i,j|u\rangle |i\rangle\!\langle j|$, or equivalently $(A_a)_{ij}=u_{ij}$.

Finally, $\sqrt2\langle i,j|\phi^+\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ and
$\sqrt2\langle i,j|\phi^-\rangle = \delta_{ij}(-1)^i$, thus
\begin{align}
2|\phi^+\rangle\!\langle\phi^+|&\to A_0 = I, \\
2|\phi^-\rangle\!\langle\phi^-|&\to A_1 = Z.
\end{align}

Comment: Am I correct in reading the last two lines as: Choi $|\phi^+\rangle\langle\phi^+|$ corresponds to a single Kraus operator $A_0$ and similarly for the other one? If so, I think normalization is off: I'd expect Kraus operators to satisfy completeness relation $\sum_k A_k^\dagger A_k=I$. Similarly, trace of a Choi should be $d=2$, not $1$. IOW, I think it should say $2|\phi^+\rangle\langle\phi^+|\to A_0 = I, 2|\phi^-\rangle\langle\phi^-|\to A_1 = Z$. Then this answer yields the same Kraus operators as the other two. Or perhaps there is another way of reading the last two lines?

Comment: @AdamZalcman indeed, you are right. I fixed the normalisation in the last equations, thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's even a more direct way than the one described by Adam. Note that every pure Choi state corresponds to a superoperator acting by conjugation. Since
$$
\mathbb{I} \otimes \mathbb{I} |\phi^+\rangle = |\phi^+\rangle, \qquad Z \otimes \mathbb{I} |\phi^+\rangle = |\phi^-\rangle,
$$
the inverse of $c_\lambda$ under the Choi-Jamiołkowski isomorphism is simply
$$
T_\lambda = \lambda\, \mathrm{id} + (1-\lambda)\, Z \cdot Z^\dagger.
$$
This gives you the Kraus operators
$$
K_1 := \sqrt{\lambda}\,\mathbb{I}, \qquad K_2:= \sqrt{1-\lambda}\, Z.
$$

---

**Remark:** In general, you can find the Kraus operators by "reshaping" the pure Choi states, since
$$
\mathcal{J}(K\cdot K^\dagger) = d^{-1}\, \mathrm{vec}(K)\mathrm{vec}(K)^\dagger,
$$
where the vectorisation isomorphism $\mathrm{vec}:\, L(\mathcal H)\simeq \mathcal H\otimes \mathcal H^* \rightarrow \mathcal H\otimes \mathcal H$ acts as
$$
\mathrm{vec}(|x\rangle\langle y|) = |x\rangle \otimes | y\rangle
$$
i.e. it applies the Riesz isomorphism to the second factor.

---

**Edit:** Sorry, I used two different conventions for the Choi-Jamiołkowski isomorphism, one where the image of a CPTP map has trace one and the other where it has trace $d$ (=dimension). Fixed the second part since OP uses first convention.

Comment: ah, sorry, I just noticed you later also included the path via the direct relation between Choi and Kraus

Comment: @glS  wow, clash of answers :D There was maybe a minute between answering and editing :)

Comment: +1 Very direct and beautiful solution indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $|\phi^+\rangle = |00\rangle+|11\rangle$ and $|\phi^-\rangle = |00\rangle-|11\rangle$ we compute

$$
c = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 2\lambda-1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2\lambda-1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\tag1.
$$

A useful property of the $d^2\times d^2$ Choi-Jamiołkowski matrix is that each of the $d^2$ $d\times d$ blocks represents the action of the channel on the matrices from the standard basis of the space of $d\times d$ matrices. In our case $d=2$ and

$$
c = \begin{pmatrix}
T\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix} & T\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\\
T\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix} & T\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}.\tag2
$$

Now, recall that the action of the phase damping channel

$$
\mathcal{F}(\rho) = p\rho + (1-p)Z\rho Z\tag3
$$

on a density matrix $\rho = \begin{pmatrix}\rho_{00}&\rho_{01}\\\rho_{10}&\rho_{11}\end{pmatrix}$ is

$$
\mathcal{F}(\rho) = \begin{pmatrix}
\rho_{00} & (2p-1)\rho_{01} \\
(2p-1)\rho_{10} & \rho_{11}
\end{pmatrix}.\tag4
$$

Substituting $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ into $(4)$ and comparing against $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that $c$ is the Choi-Jamiołkowski matrix of the phase damping channel with $p=\lambda$.

Consequently, $(3)$ is the Kraus representation of the channel with Choi-Jamiołkowski matrix $c$. The channel shrinks the equator of the Bloch sphere, see e.g. figure 8.9 on page 377 in Nielsen & Chuang. Finally, when $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ then the output of the channel is separable regardless of the input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do we need the phase damping channel?

Comment: As the answer shows, you are asking about the Choi-Jamiołkowski matrix of the phase damping channel. This realization gives us the Kraus representation.

Comment: But in my question it isn't obvious that the C-J matrix is for the phase damping channel. I'm not seeing how we should use the phase damping channel. It's just "the quantum channel" in the question.

Comment: It isn't obvious. However, when you calculate the elements of $c$, i.e. $(1)$ then the elements $2\lambda - 1$ are very suggestive since they look like the $2p-1$ factors by which the phase damping channel multiplies the off-diagonal elements of the input density matrix, see $(4)$.

Comment: Yea but I think the solution shouldn't involve knowing what phase damping is. Just finding simply the Kraus matrices is what is being asked.

Comment: As usual, there are many paths to solution. IMHO, recognizing and exploiting well-known objects when they appear in a chain of reasoning leads to simpler, faster and more interesting solutions than a run-of-the-mill calculation :-)

Comment: Right but it's like using a result from Analysis III to solve an Analysis I exercise. Obviously it's easy to do but when it's not given (nor taught where I am getting this exercise from) then it makes the solution useless.

Comment: FWIW, phase damping channel is one of the simplest quantum channels. Most textbooks describe it early on in discussion of quantum channels (Nielsen & Chuang, Kitaev & Shen & Vyalyi). OTOH, many textbooks either never get to Choi–Jamiołkowski at all or describe it after introducing a few example channels which generally include simple channels like phase damping.

Comment: My statement still holds. I still don't understand how your solution finds the Kraus operators how you get from (1) to (2), (2) to (3) and then (3) to (4).

Comment: (2) doesn't follow from (1). It's a property of every Choi–Jamiołkowski matrix that can be verified directly from definition. (3) doesn't follow from (2). It's a definition. (4) follows from (3) by substituting $\rho$ and carrying out the calculation.

Comment: (2) is an interesting observation, but you need to define the Choi as $c=(I\otimes T)|m\rangle\!\langle m|$ for it to work (with the channel on the right), correct? This way you get $(\langle i|\otimes I)c(|k\rangle\otimes I)=T(E_{ik})$ which should correspond to the block structure you mention

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you define the Choi as $(T\otimes I)|m\rangle\langle m|$ then you can still pick out the output of $T$ on the standard basis matrices, but the process is less visually appealing because the elements become interspersed. However, in the case of $(1)$ both yield the same result because of all the zeros in the matrix. IOW, $(T\otimes I)|m\rangle\langle m|$ and $(I\otimes T)|m\rangle\langle m|$ have the same four corner elements.